# Controladores en CodeIgniter: no consigo hacerlos funcionar

Tags: php, codeigniter, apache, xampp

Un saludo.

Intento explicarme lo mejor posible, porque es algo complejo. Cualquier información que falte, me lo ponéis en los comentarios y la doy sin problema.

Tengo XAMMP 3.3.0 sobre Windows 11. Ahí ejecuto el servidor Apache. Dentro de la carpeta `C:\xampp\htdocs` es donde he colocado CodeIgniter 4.1.8, en una carpeta llamada `ci`, quedando así:

[image: Carpeta htdocs]

Bien, ahora, dentro de ci, tengo esta estructura (fijaos en lo marcado en rojo):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**app** es la carpeta de aplicación por defecto, y **webapp** es la que yo debo usar, y en la que debo montar mi aplicación. Se generó haciendo un copia-pega de **app**.

Si voy a localhost/ci/public, veo la web por defecto de "bienvenido a CodeIgniter 4.1.8", lo que quiere decir que el servidor responde.

Como yo quiero trabajar con la carpeta **webapp** he editado el archivo `"C:\xampp\htdocs\ci\public\.htaccess"` y colocado esta línea así:

```
    # If you installed CodeIgniter in a subfolder, you will need to
    # change the following line to match the subfolder you need.
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase
    RewriteBase /webapp/
```

Ahora quiero crear un controlador de prueba, como el que se incluye en la propia documentación de CodeIgniter:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

class Helloworld extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        echo 'Hello World!';
    }
}
```

Para ello, me voy a `webapp/Controllers` y ubico ahí el archivo **Hello.php**, con el código que se ve sobre este párrafo.

Ahora, se supone que dirigiéndome con un navegador a `http://localhost/webapp/hello` debe de funcionar, pero lo único que obtengo es un 404 Not Found:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Supuestamente (o, al menos, según los apuntes que tengo) esto debe de funcionar. Pero no hay forma. También he probado a meter el **index.php** en la URL por si acaso: `http://localhost/webapp/index.php/hello`, pero el resultado es exactamente el mismo.

Por seguir probado cosas, me he llevado ese mismo **Hello.php** a la carpeta **app** por defecto: `"C:\xampp\htdocs\ci\app\Controllers\Hello.php"`. Dado que a la web por defecto se entra con `http://localhost/ci/public/`, he intuido que para llegar a **Hello** tendré que usar `http://localhost/ci/public/index.php/hello`, lo cual genera también un error 404, pero esta vez de apariencia diferente, lo que me da a entender que CodeIgniter sí ha llegado a ejecutarse alguna forma.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si alguien me puede echar una mano, lo agradezco bastante.

Comment: Codeigniter tiene un sistema de rutas ya establecidas, es posible entrar en la url `http://localhost/webapp/hello` si tu carpeta ci la renombras a webapp y creas un controlador en un archivo Hello.php con el nombre de clase Hello, es necesario que lo escribas en mayusculas, aunque accediendo por url lo utlices en minusculas

Comment: Gracias por responder. La carpeta ```ci``` se tiene que llamar tal cual, eso no puedo cambiarlo, pues es la carpeta de CodeIgniter. Donde yo tengo que implementar mis cosas es en ```webapp```. Por tanto, haciendo lo que me dices y renombrando la clase, intuyo que se accede con ```http://localhost/ci/webapp/hello```, pero ahora obtengo un ```403 Forbidden: You don't have permission to access this resource```. ¿Por qué? Me vuelvo loco ya con esto... menos mal que los apuntes que tengo son muy buenos :/

Comment: ¿Cúal es la url final que necesitas? ¿`http://localhost/webapp/hello`  o `http://localhost/ci/webapp/hello`(con el ci) ?

Comment: Idealmente en el manual se indica la primera (sin ci), pero como no es el mejor que he visto, y sé que la carpeta **ci** debe seguir llamándose así, la segunda debe valerme.

Answer (score 0):

Si necesitas acceder a tu aplicación desde la url http://localhost/ci/webapp/hello
necesitas primero renombrar la carpeta `public` por `webapp` en ella encontrarás el archivo `index.php` que es el que controla toda la aplicación.

Podras acceder a la vista por defecto de CodeIgniter si entras a http://localhost/ci/webapp

Después debes crear un archivo de controlador dentro de la carpeta `app\Controllers` tanto el nombre del archivo como el de la clase deben ser los mismos y empezar con una letra mayúscula, tambien puede contener una función `index` por ejemplo:

**Hello.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;
use CodeIgniter\Controller;

class Hello extends Controller {

    public function index(){
        echo 'Hola!';
    }
}
```

Verás que podrás acceder por url al controlador con http://localhost/ci/webapp/index.php/hello

Si necesitas quitar de la url el `index.php` basta con descomentar la linea del `RewriteBase` en el archivo `.htaccess` que se encunetra junto al `index.php` de la carpeta webapp y agregar la ruta de la subcarpeta

```
# If you installed CodeIgniter in a subfolder, you will need to
# change the following line to match the subfolder you need.
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase
RewriteBase /ci/webapp/
```